# How to deploy Windows Embedded Standard?

Tags: deployment, pxe-boot

What is the usual workflow of deploying Windows Embedded Standard 2009 on clients? I haven't found an official guide yet and would appreciate a link.  Is additional software needed for deployment? What can I do if clients do not support PXE?

Comment: "on client like"? Clients like what?

Comment: Whoops, that "like" was only part of the expression: "what does xy look like?". I removed it.
The question is not related to a special client. 
I'd just like to know how WES2009 is deployed on clients with PXE and on clients without PXE.

Answer (score 2):

See the links/articles in the "Deployment" section on this site for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/standard/aa731380.aspx